# Converting pure SQL query to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, async-await, sqlalchemy

I have two problems. Convert to async SQLAlchemy and "search_title" may be `None` so how to implement condition like if "search_title" is none, return all in query.

````
          "SELECT manager.title, manager.status, COUNT(car) AS total_cars,"
            "COUNT(CASE WHEN cars.status='active' THEN 1 END) AS active_cars, "
            "manager.created_at FROM manager FULL JOIN shops ON manager.id=cars.manager_id "
            f"WHERE manager.title ILIKE '%{search_title}%' "
            "GROUP BY manager.created_at, manager.status, manager.title "
            f"ORDER BY manager.{ordering_statement.key} "
            f"LIMIT {pagination.limit} "
)```
````

Comment: Because ILIKE is a useful extension made by PostgreSQL

Comment: Have you tried anything ? What classes or tables have you defined in SQLAlchemy ? Please edit your post and provide these additional details.

Answer (score 0):

My solution converting pure SQL to async SQLAlchemy:

```
query = await self.session.execute(
                select(
                    [
                        self.model.title,
                        self.model.status,
                        func.count(CarDB.id).label('total_cars'),
                        func.count(CarDB.id).filter(CarDB.status == 'active').label('active_cars'),
                        self.model.created_at
                    ]
                )
                .select_from(CarDB)
                .join(
                    self.model,
                    self.model.id == CarDB.manager_id,
                    full=True
                )
                .filter(
                    self.model.title.contains(search_title)
                )
                .group_by(self.model.id)
                .order_by(ordering_statement)
                .offset(offset)
                .limit(limit)
            )

            query_data = query.mappings().all()
```